# Regex Negated character class problem, Scala

Tags: regex, scala

With this code I'm trying to get only "key" and "value" from the string.
But function return None. If I change `[^"]+` to `.+` then it would return result but value would contain none-needed part as well. How to fix this issue?

```
def parseLine(line: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
    val exportRegex = """\s*export\s+(\S+)\s*="([^"]+)"""".r
    line match {
      case exportRegex(key, value) =>Some(key, value)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

parseLine("""export key="value" #"none-needed"""")
```

Comment: You are right @jwvh. It works. Thank you. Can you write an answer instead of the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ...`([^"]+)"""` means that the input should end with the capture group, even before any closing quote mark.

To fix it you can A) add `.*` at the end (i.e. ...`([^"]+).*"""`) or B) make the regex `.unanchored`, in which case you can probably drop the `\s*` at the beginning.